# Correct json-ld representation for software benchmarks

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

I'm building a web page comparing multiple web application frameworks: let's say framework A, B, C have RPS (request per second) 3.42, 1.24, 2.18. What would be the accurate JSON-LD representation of this comparison, valid also according to https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Additional Property: https://schema.org/additionalProperty
This is a catch-all property that lets you define properties and values.

There are schemas that let you define measurements, but requests/second is not  an accepted unit (https://schema.org/unitCode).